# Regex pattern to match numbers in certain conditions

Tags: c#, regex, revit-api

First time posting, please forgive the formatting. Not really a programmer, I work in C# with the Revit and AutoCAD APi's. Important to note, as the Revit API is a bit of mess, so the same code may produce different results in a different API. So I have three basic string patterns where I want to return certain numbers depending on what their prefix & suffix. They could be surrounded by other text than what I show, and the actual numbers and positions within the string may vary.

**String 1:** (12) #4x2'-0 @ 6 EF

**String 2:** (12) #4 @ 6 EF

**String 3:** STAGGER 2'-0, SPCG AT 6 AT 12 SLAB

The code I'm using:

```
if (LengthAsString.IsMatch(remarkdata) == true)
{
    Regex remarklength = new Regex(@"isnertRegexPatternhere");
    if (remarklength.IsMatch(remarkdata))
    {
        remarkdata = remarklength.Replace(remarkdata, "${0}\u0022");
    }
}
```

remarkdata is the strings from above, and im adding inch marks " after each number match.

The patterns ive tested and their returns:

```
                                 String 1   String 2   String 3
    \d+(?!['-]|([(\d+)]))        0,6        4,6        0,6,12
    (?<![#])\d+                  12,2,0,6   12,6       2,9,6,12
    \d+(?= @)|(?<=@ )\d+         0,6        6          no matches
```

---

```
     expected results:           0,6        6          0,6,12
```

so im close, but no cigar. Thoughts?

Double Edit: looking for the numbers that aren't preceded by #, nor between (). Ignore @ and x, they may or may not be there.

Comment: Your requirements are ambiguous. Please formulate them verbally.

Comment: edited. i think that clears it up?

Comment: At first I came with `(?<!#)\d+(?!.*(?:['-]|[#x]\d))`, but your edit does not clear it out.

Comment: Actually that seems to work perfectly. so for my future use, what exactly (before the edit) was ambiguous about my requirements?

Comment: You want to match `0` before `@` in the first string, and you do not want to match `4` (also before `@`) in the second string. Why? And as per the edit, you want to get `2`, `0` and `6` from `(12) #4x2'-0 @ 6 EF`.

Comment: ah okay i think i know what you meant. the why is i'm going to add " after them. So what im really looking for is in the second edit. All that being said, if you would more your solution so i can mark it as solution?

Comment: Ok, let me post my solution, but feel free to ask for clarifications since you might need to further tune it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
(?<!#)\d+(?!.*(?:['-]|[#x]\d))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%23%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F!.*%28%3F%3A%5B%27-%5D%7C%5B%23x%5D%5Cd%29%29&i=%2812%29%20%234x2%27-0%20%40%206%20EF%0D%0A%2812%29%20%234%20%40%206%20EF%0D%0ASTAGGER%202%27-0%2C%20SPCG%20AT%206%20AT%2012%20SLAB)

**Details**

- `(?<!#)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `#` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits (or `[0-9]+` to only match ASCII digits)
- `(?!.*(?:['-]|[#x]\d))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match once there are any 0+ chars other than newline (`.*`) followed with `'`, `-`, or `#`/`x` followed with a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Note that in case your strings always have balanced non-nested parentheses, and you may have `(123)` substrings after `#` or `x1`, you may also want to add `[^()]*\)` into the lookahead

```
(?<!#)\d+(?!.*(?:['-]|[#x]\d)|[^()]*\))
```

to avoid matching digits inside the parentheses.

See [another .NET demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%23%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F!.*%28%3F%3A%5B%27-%5D%7C%5B%23x%5D%5Cd%29%7C%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%5C%29%29&i=%2812%29%20%234x2%27-0%20%40%206%20EF%20%2855%29).